# Error when trying to use SFLM Vertex: "Vertex is not a member of sf"

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using SFML, and I've been trying to work with Vertex Arrays, but whenever I write something like

```
sf::Vertex vertex;
```

and compile, it gives me an error saying

> 'Vertex' is not a member of sf

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<Vertex.hpp>

int main(){
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "SFML WORKS");
  sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
  shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);


  while (window.isOpen())
  {
      sf::Event event;
      while (window.pollEvent(event))
      {
          if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
              window.close();
      }

      window.clear();
      window.draw(shape);
      window.display();
  }
  sf::Vertex vertex;

  return 0;
}
```

It now also gives me an error saying:

```
"SFMLtest.cpp:3:9: fatal error: Vertex.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include<Vertex.hpp>"
```

Comment: Show the code. It's of no use to post telling us about an error you get without any indication of how you got there; it just leads to useless speculation. But on that note, make sure you simply included the right header...

Comment: [One requirement is `#include <Vertex.hpp>`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Vertex.php). Do you have that in your code?

Comment: Read the Help Centre about How To Ask. Essential info should not be dumped in comments. Comments are for additional discussion only. [Edit] your post to include all the information that readers need to assess it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added the code into the post.

Comment: Move to the next step in your 'How to compile code for beginners' tutorial: telling your compiler where to find includes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<Vertex.hpp>
```

The above line should read

```
#include <SFML/Graphics/Vertex.hpp>
```

**But** you should not need it at all, because `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` already *does that for you*. So simply delete that include vertex line altogether.